# Async programming against non-async services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, threadpool

This past year we've been working on a new web app that calls into our company's existing service layer.

We made the decision to wrap up all of our service oriented calls into our own service layer (which I'll refer to as our web-service layer) so that the details of which services we use (we'll move to a new API at some point in the future) are hidden from the web layer itself.

We also decided that most of our web-service layer methods would return `Task<T>`.

As it stands, the underlying services that we call are not async and so there are some concerns that our web-service layer will max out the available threads and cause problems when we have a large volume of users.

I'm looking for information, one way or the other, to further understand how our decision to return `Task<T>` will impact our site and whether or not we need to consider changing our return types.

We'll be moving to VS2012 at some point but right now we're using VS2010 and are not using `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 1):

> As it stands, the underlying services that we call are not async and
>   so there are some concerns that our web-service layer will max out the
>   available threads and cause problems when we have a large volume of
>   users.

Yes that's something you should be concerned with. I would recommend you doing this only if you have real asynchronous methods. But simply wrapping blocking synchronous methods into an async API will be worse than calling the synchronous methods directly from the consuming code. In an ASP.NET application you will get benefit from asynchronous calls only if the underlying API is relying on I/O Completion Ports. Otherwise it's just a waste of resource.

The only useful scenario in which you could do that is if your methods could be called in parallel instead of sequentially. This is possible only is the different methods are not connected between them. In this case you could indeed wrap your sync methods in async tasks.

Comment: We do call all of our web-service layer methods in parallel (using Task.WaitAll).

Comment: Alright, in this case there could be a justification to do that, as I mentioned in my answer.